# Github CLI add another remote and work with it

Tags: git, git-remote, github-cli

I started using Github CLI after its first release, that's a great tool. I've been working on a project, which needs to be in different places remotely, e.g. in two repositories. I can add another remote to push changes to it, but gh will only be able to control the initial one. As an example, `gh pr status` command in a repo which has two or more remotes, will only show data of origin remote. How can i switch between the remotes to see all actions like issues and pr's on each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`gh` 2.21.0 (Dec. 2022)](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.21.0), you can use the new command [`gh repo set-default`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_set-default)

> This command sets the default remote repository to use when querying the GitHub API for the locally cloned repository.
>
> `gh` uses the default repository for things like:
>
> - viewing and creating pull requests
> - viewing and creating issues
> - viewing and creating releases
> - working with Actions
> - adding repository and environment secrets

This will avoid the interactive message `Which should be the base repository?`.
From now on (2.21.0+), `gh` commands in a repository with multiple remotes will now error out until a default has been chosen.

---

With [gh v2.22.0 (Jan. 2023)](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.22.0), `gh repo set-default` *also* works with remote *bare* repositories. ([PR 6880](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/6880))

---

With [gh v2.30.0 (May 2023)](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.30.0), you can use `gh repo set-default --view` *without* repo argument ([PR 7441](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/7441)), in order to see the current default repository.