# How to create GitHub Codespace from current git directory repository?

Tags: git, github, codespaces

I want through the terminal to create a new codespace on Github, from the current git repository.

I can create codespace from `gh` with this params

```bash
$ gh codespace create
? Repository: [? for help, tab for suggestions]
```

and then enter repo name with `username/repo-name` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the repo name with username/repo-name format from the git URL, and then create a codespace from them.

1. get git repository URL

```bash
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

2. remove domain and .git from URL to have `username/repo-name` format

```bash
$ git config --get remote.origin.url  | sed 's/https:\/\/github\.com\///' | sed 's/\.git$//'
```

3. pipe name to gh command

```bash
$ git config --get remote.origin.url  | sed 's/https:\/\/github\.com\///' | sed 's/\.git$//' | xargs gh codespace create -r
```

Answer (score 1):

[gh 2.21.0 (Dec. 2022)](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.21.0) adds two new elements:

- Use `-R` for `--repo` shorthand and deprecate `-r`
- [`gh codespace create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_codespace_create): allow setting display name for the new codespace.

So:

```bash
cd /path/to/current/local/repository
gh repo set-default
gh codespace create -R $(gh repo view --json owner,name --jq '"\(.name)/\(.owner.login)"') \
   --display-name yourName
```

See "[Github CLI add another remote and work with it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74916062/6309)" on the new necessity to define your current repository as the default one.

See [`gh` formatting](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_help_formatting) on `--json --jq` formatting options, which allows to extract `owner/name` from the current repository:

```
gh repo view --json owner,name --jq '"\(.name)/\(.owner.login)"'

# on CMD Windows
gh repo view --json owner,name --jq "\"\(.name)/\(.owner.login)\""
```

Comment: @njfamirm Also [posted on Mastodon](https://fosstodon.org/@vonc/109585334159967290).